# Mathematica For Loop with conditions problem

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, iteration, wolfram-mathematica

I'm using Mathematica, and I have a problem with putting conditions on my For Loop. I explain :

I have two functions

```
f[x,y,t]
z[x,y,t]
```

I want to put a conditon that let me do :

> for all x€[-a,a] and y€[-b,b] and t€[0,139] : If z[x,y,t]>0 Then
> f[x,y,t]==0, and if not then let f[x,y,t] have its original values.

What I'm trying to do is like a numerical Heaviside function.

So what I did, is the following :

```
xx = Table[k, {k, -a, a, a/69}];
yy = Table[k, {k, -b, b, b/69}];
tt = Table[k, {k, 1, 139, 1}];
```

`For[t = 1, t < 140, t++, If[z[xx[[t]], yy[[t]], t] > 0, f[xx[[t]], yy[[t]], t] == 0, Continue]]`

This doesnt show any errors, but when I try to replace with values, it seems not changing anything on my f[x,y,t] function.

How can I do to make it work ?

What I want is that any element of f[x,y] for any fixed t will be replaced by 0 if z[x,y] for any fixed t is upper than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
f[x_, y_, t_] := x[[t]] + y[[t]] + t 
z[x_, y_, t_] := 2*x[[t]] + 3*y[[t]] + t

xx = Table[k, {k, -a, a, a/69}];
yy = Table[k, {k, -b, b, b/69}];
tt = Table[k, {k, 1, 139, 1}];

a = 1234;
b = 4321;

output = {};

For[t = 1, t < 140, t++,
 If[z[xx, yy, t] > 0,
  AppendTo[output, 0],
  AppendTo[output, f[xx, yy, t]]]]

ListLinePlot[output]
```

Which could be also be done by

```
output = Array[
   If[z[xx, yy, #] > 0, 0, f[xx, yy, #]] &, Length[tt]];

ListLinePlot[output]
```

Comment: Sorry It doesn't do what I want. Let say f[x,y,t]:=x[[t]]+y[[t]]+t and z[x,y,t]:=2*x[[t]]+3*y[[t]]+t. What I want is that for all the plan (x,y) and for all t : if z>0 then f==0, otherwise, f can have it's normal values

Comment: @User012928477 I changed my answer.  Is this now correct? or what doesn't work?

Comment: The first code doesnt give me what I want. Because my f[x,y,t] must be a 2D matrix for each t. I should have 139 2D matrix for t=1 to 139. But your code will give 1D vectors. I tried to put output={ , } and output = {{}} but It didn't work for me.  The seconde code seems to be the best one (it seems to be the best solution because it replace the values inside the matrix directly without changing the position of the values in the matrix), but it didn't evaluate for me. When I try to evaluate it, it only replace the matrixes and let all the "If" statements without evaluating them...